# How does strcmp work in C in this case? I have an array to loop through and a char which needs to be compared with each element in the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings, strcmp

I have a array called notes which is

```
char *NOTES[] = {"A", "Bb", "B", "C", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "Gb", "G", "Ab"};
```

I then need to implement a function which gets the notes index

```
int get_note_index(char* string) {}
```

I thought of using the strcmp pre-written method to compare the parameter passed into the argument which is string and the elements of the notes array.

I did something like `strcmp(string,NOTES[i])` where `i` is incremented with a for loop.

Note: the string passed is a note itself, such as `A` where the output would be `0`, since after a successful comparison `NOTES[0]` would match with the argument string. `1` for `"Bb"` and so on.

I'm new to C so I don't know how to effectively use `strcmp()` or if it can even be used like this.

Comment: Welcome so stackoverflow! "I did something like `strcmp(string,NOTES[i])`" show us that exact something, please, and tell us what your exact output was, and how it differed from your expected output. Please read [example]

Comment: Just typed this up https://ideone.com/BHnYD7. It prints out what's returned from `strcmp`. What does your code look like?

Comment: @jiveturkey your link is broken

Comment: I see that.  Odd.  Try it now.

Comment: What language are you using?  Is it C++ or C?  If it's C, the tag should be C without the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration should look like

```
size_t get_note_index( const char *a[], size_t n, const char *s );
```

That is you have to pass the number of elements in the array that will be used in a loop within the function.

If the string is not found then the function returns the position after the last element of the array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t get_note_index( const char *a[], size_t n, const char *s ) 
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && strcmp( a[i], s ) != 0 ) ++i;

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char * NOTES[] = 
    {
        "A", "Bb", "B", "C", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "Gb", "G", "Ab"
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( NOTES ) / sizeof( *NOTES );

    const char *s = "Db";

    size_t pos = get_note_index( NOTES, N, s );

    if ( pos != N )
    {
        printf( "The index of the string \"%s\" is %zu\n", s, pos );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The string \"%s\" is not found\n", s );
    }

    s = "Bd";

    pos = get_note_index( NOTES, N, s );

    if ( pos != N )
    {
        printf( "The index of the string \"%s\" is %zu\n", s, pos );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The string \"%s\" is not found\n", s );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The index of the string "Db" is 4
The string "Bd" is not found
```

Comment: Note: I read _somewhere_ that the next C spec will promote `size_t n, const char *a[]` over `const char *a[], size_t n`.. Maybe  to support VLA in signatures.   Not a issue for this answer, but  looks like a future trend.

Answer (score 0):

your solution will resemble:

```
int get_note_index(char* string) {

   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      if (strcmp(string, NOTES[i]) == 0) {
         return i;
      }
   }

  return -1; // not found
}
```

You may want to replace 12 with a #define for the size of the tone row.  Here I return -1 if the note doesn't match.